# Postgres Large Text Search Advice

Tags: postgresql

I'm quite new to databases, and am looking for some high level advice.

**The Situation**
I'm building a database using Postgres 9.3, within the database is a table in which I store log files.

```
CREATE TABLE errorlogs (
     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     archive_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES archives,
     filename VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
     content TEXT);
```

The text in content can vary in length anywhere from 1k to 50MB.

**The Problem**
I'd like to be able to perform reasonably fast text searches on the data within the "content" column (eg, WHERE CONTENT LIKE '%some_error%'). Right now the searches are very slow (>10 minutes to search through 8206 rows).

I know that indexing is intended to be the solution to my problem, but I don't seem to be able to create indexes -- whenever I try I get errors that the index would be too large.

> =# CREATE INDEX error_logs_content_idx ON errorlogs (content text_pattern_ops); 
> ERROR:  index row requires 1796232 bytes,
>   maximum size is 8191

I was hoping for some advice on how to get around this problem. Can I change the maximum index size? Or should I not be trying to use Postgres for full text search on text fields as large as this?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I think you are probably looking for full-text search/indexing http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-intro.html.

Comment: This answer might also help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the advice. I've already gone through the textsearch docs, and I couldn't find any information on the index limitations. The second comment you posted describes creating a text_pattern_ops index, which as I mentioned above, returns an error about the index being too large.

Comment: You want to be using a gin or gist index, rather than a B-tree, which is what text_pattern_ops work on. Apologies for bad link.

Comment: I've tried that too, I get similar errors about the data being too large for a tsvector using something like:

WHERE to_tsvector(content) @@ to_tsquery('Stacktrace')

(with no index)

Comment: I get NOTICES, not ERRORS, when using to_tsvector on strings that contain very large words.  Although if your content contains words over 2047 characters long, I have to wonder if it is not really binary data, which could mean it can have \0 characters which will cause problems.

Comment: The data I am indexing is definitely not binary. They are very large log files, and there is a chance there could be a "word" over 2047 characters long. Do you happen to have a link to information on these limits? It would be really helpful...

Comment: I don't know that the 2047 limit is documented anywhere.  I am just going empirically off from what I see with `select to_tsvector('simple',(select string_agg(md5(x::text),'') from generate_series(1,1000) x(x))||' Stacktrace' );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text search vectors can't handle data this big --- see [documented limits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-limitations.html).  Their strength is fuzzy searching, so you can search for 'swim' and finding 'swim,' 'swimming,' 'swam,' and 'swum' in the same call.  They are not meant to replace `grep`.

The reason for the limits are in the [source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ts__type_8h_source.html) as MAXSTRLEN (and MAXSTRPOS).  Text search vectors are stored in one long, continuous array up to 1 MiB in length (total of all characters for all unique lexemes).  To access these, the ts_vector index structure allows 11 bits for word length and 20 bits for its position in the array.  These limits allow the index structure fit into a 32-bit unsigned int.

You are probably running into one or both of these limits if you have either too many unique words in a file OR words are repeated very frequently --- something quite possible if you have 50MB log file with quasi-random data.

Are you sure you need to store log files in a database?  You're basically replicating the file system, and `grep` or `python` can do the searching there quite nicely.  If you really need to, though, you might consider this:

```
CREATE TABLE errorlogs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    , archive_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES archives
    , filename VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE log_lines (
    line PRIMARY KEY
    , errorlog INTEGER REFERENCES errorlogs(id)
    , context TEXT
    , tsv TSVECTOR
);

CREATE INDEX log_lines_tsv_idx ON log_lines USING gin( line_tsv );
```

Here, you treat each log *line* as a "document."  To search, you'd do something like

```
SELECT e.id, e.filename, g.line, g.context
FROM errorlogs e JOIN log_lines g ON e.id = g.errorlog 
WHERE g.tsv @@ to_tsquery('some & error');
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. I have since switched to storing a single log line per row. I haven't yet tried indexing though -- just tried this and it works nicely. Thanks again!